# Is there a way to test offer codes in iOS app without using storekit config file

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

I have a react native app thats live for iOS. It also has apple subscription feature enabled. For the same product i would like to add the offer code using the presentCodeRedemptionSheet in app. However i am unable to test it(Except storekit ie local). Since purchase notification has to be implemented in backend server, the storekit way is not helpful. I would like to know if there is any other way to test the apple offer codes